# Pure CSS Slider with Navigation and Autoplay

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling at work to figure this out for a week and can't quite figure it out and none of my friends know HTML/CSS so I thought why not ask here? I work on my company’s internal website, it's kinda crap none of the apps work. They have a carousel that we don't much care for that I'm trying to get rid of so I was going to make a new one... only issue is the site doesn't allow any scripts or java so I'm really just limited to basic html and css and I can't for the life of me figure out how to animations to work. I've figured out how to make a carousel by researching online that's fine that seems pretty straight forward, animating photos on their own seems straightforward... but trying to make an animation with any kind of control without java or scripts of any kind I can't figure it out. Was hoping someone could help me make a super basic one even if it's just a general image rotator with a hover to pause, but preferably something that rotates automatically and has navigation arrows or page dots...

I found this as something that might work for our site, but I need to reach out to our provider to find out why our host site is replacing the ">" between ".st-slider > #play1:checked" with garbage text preventing me from seeing if this animation will actually work (It should since there are no scripts running it and other keyanimation based css sliders work on our site). Then I would like it to look better... But to give an idea of what kind of project I'm looking at please see the link below.

https://codepen.io/miriamcc/pen/KzGGqZ

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello dear did you try to use

```
@keyframes
```

?

that would do the automated part of the work

Comment: I tried it... only issue is I'm having a hard time understanding really how to use them. I can make a basic animation with keyframes fine, I can make the navigation fine, but figuring out how to get them working together or how to even set something like that up I don't even know. I'm not really that good at html/css. I've looked at tons of separate examples and tried a number of ways to combine them and idk nothing ever works for me.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry but to work both animated and indicator part is impossible with pure css, as far as I know, you could try to add a bit of bootstrap at least